# How to solve a linear system by LinearSolve when the variables are duplicate?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

Given that I have a set of equations about varible $x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n$, which own the following style:

$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x_0 \\
 x_1 \\
 x_2 \\
 x_3 \\
 x_4 \\
 \color{red}{x_0} \\
 \color{red}{x_1} \\
 \color{red}{x_2} \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 (1,1) \\
 (2,3) \\
 (3,-1) \\
 (4,1) \\
 (5,0) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

Obviously, I **cannot** solve this linear system by `LinearSolve[]`. To solve this equation group, I only used the `Solve[]`.

```
mat=
 {{1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0}};
eqns = mat.{x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x0, x1, x2};
```

$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{x_0}{6}+\frac{2 x_1}{3}+\frac{x_2}{6}\\
\frac{x_1}{6}+\frac{2 x_2}{3}+\frac{x_3}{6}\\
\frac{x_2}{6}+\frac{2 x_3}{3}+\frac{x_4}{6}\\
\frac{x_0}{6}+\frac{x_3}{6}+\frac{2 x_4}{3}\\
\frac{2 x_0}{3}+\frac{x_1}{6}+\frac{x_4}{6}
\end{pmatrix}
$

```
yValues = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
part1 = {x0, x1, x2, x3, x4} /. 
  Solve[Thread[eqns == yValues[[All, 1]]], {x0, x1, x2, x3, x4}]
part2 = {x0, x1, x2, x3, x4} /. 
  Solve[Thread[eqns == yValues[[All, 2]]], {x0, x1, x2, x3, x4}]
res = Transpose[Join[part1, part2]]
```

> ```
>  {{75/11, -8/11}, {-9/11, 4/11}, {27/11, 58/11}, {3, -38/11}, {39/11, 28/11}}
> ```

#### Question

However, the index $n$ for variables $\{x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ is very large ($n=100$) in my work. My solution that by `Solve[]` is very cockamamie. So I would like to know how to deal with this case by the *built-in* `LinearSolve[]` efficiently?

Comment: You can partition your x-vector as $(x,y,x)$, where $x=(x_0,x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(x_3,x_4)$, and your matrix `mat` in a similar way (3x3 block matrix). Multiplying out the blocks and collecting $x$ and $y$ together will give you the linear system of reduced size that you can feed to `LinearSolve`

Comment: Do a fold-over: $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac16&\frac23&\frac16&0&0\\ 0&\frac16&\frac23&\frac16&0\\ 0&0&\frac16&\frac23&\frac16\\ \frac16&0&0&\frac16&\frac23\\ \frac23&\frac16&0&0&\frac16\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x_0\\x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}(1,1)\\(2,3)\\(3,-1)\\(4,1)\\(5,0)\\\end{pmatrix}$$ Is this part of your closed spline interpolation problem?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Tr6.png)

Comment: Maybe I missed something in your question. But once you have the equations, you can find the corresponding matrix by CoefficientArrays[eqns, {x0, x1, x2, x3, x4}][[2]] and then use LinearSolve.

Comment: @FredSimons Yes, your method is right. I have achieved the right result by your method:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to fold a "wide" matrix over to enforce "periodic" conditions:

```
mat = {{1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0}};

{m, n} = Dimensions[mat];

LinearSolve[Take[mat, m, m] + PadRight[Take[mat, m, m - n], {m, m}],
            {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}]
```

> ```
> {{75/11, -8/11}, {-9/11, 4/11}, {27/11, 58/11}, {3, -38/11}, {39/11, 28/11}}
> ```

Comment: Is fold-over the "official" name for this operation?

Comment: I'm not aware of an official name, but I like the picturesque terminology. :)

Comment: I agree. It was just that you so confidently calling it "fold-over" in your comment made me feel like I should have known that it was actually a thing :-)

Comment: J.M. I would like to ask you a question about **well-condition**. For a square matrix $A$, I can use the formula $cond(A)=||A|||A^{-1}|||$ to calculate the conditional number of matrix $A$. However, I didn't know **which value** is proper for **well-condition**. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Shutao, the idea with conditioning is that the nearer the condition is to $1$, the better the conditioning of the problem (as in the case of orthogonal/unitary matrices). Ill-conditioned systems have large condition numbers, and truly singular systems have infinite condition numbers.

Comment: @J.M. For instance, `LinearSolve[{{1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0, 0}, {0, 1/6, 2/3, 1/6, 0}, {0, 0, 1/6,
    2/3, 1/6}, {1/6, 0, 0, 1/6, 2/3}, {2/3, 1.0/6, 0, 0, 1/6}}]` gives the conditional number is `2.82`. However, if I constructed a set of matrice by a method, I would like to know is it possible for me to prove that it is well-conditioned.

Comment: It depends on how the matrix is built., @Shutao. But that might be a long discussion unrelated to this thread; let's do it in the chatroom.

Answer (score 4):

```
l = 5; s = 3;
(* Solution 1 *)
# + SparseArray[#2, {l, l}] & @@ Internal`PartitionRagged[mat\[Transpose], {l, s}];
LinearSolve[%\[Transpose], yValues]

(* Solution 2 *)
Module[{m = #[[;; l]]}, m[[;; s]] += #[[-s ;;]]; m] &[mat\[Transpose]];
LinearSolve[%\[Transpose], yValues]
```

Comment: Cool, `Internal\`PartitionRagged` can be very useful!

Answer (score 2):

This script accepts the equations (consistent equations) with the unknowns in any order.

```
vars = Variables[eqns]
A = Grad[eqns, vars]
B1 = Map[First, yValues]
B2 = Map[Last, yValues]
LinearSolve[A, B1]
LinearSolve[A, B2]
```